# Connecting to oracle database using tnsname.ora with liquibase

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I want to use liquibase to automate database deployments. Our setup is tnsnames.ora file is located on a shared drive `\\shared\drive\path\tnsnames.ora`

As per docs from liquibase, liquibase.properties files should look something like as below.

```
--driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
--classpath=ojdbc14.jar
--url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@<IP OR HOSTNAME>:<PORT>/<SERVICE NAME OR SID>"  
--changeLogFile=db.changelog-1.0.xml
--username=<USERNAME>
--password=<PASSWORD>
```

Is there any way by which we can just specify `<SERVICE NAME OR SID>` which get the matching `SERVICE NAME` from tnsname.ora file located on the network share and connect to the required database ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Liquibase built into SQLcl](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer-command-line/20.4/sqcug/using-liquibase-sqlcl.html#GUID-3556315C-6D82-4D58-9B62-DBDDCEBF9D61)? SQLcl version 20.4 has Liquibase version 4.1.1 embedded within it so you can connect to the database using the same syntax that you would use for SQLPlus, then run your Liquibase commands from there.

```sql
C:\Users\ej>sql scott/tiger@tnsalias

SQLcl: Release 20.4 Production on Fri Mar 05 11:07:13 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Fri Mar 05 2021 11:07:14 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0


SQL> lb version


Liquibase version:   4.1.1
Extension Version:   20.4.1.0

SQL> lb help


usage: lb COMMAND ...

Commands:
  The following commands are available within the liquibase feature.
  lb help COMMAND for command specific help

  COMMAND
    genobject            Generate change log for a specific database object
    genschema            Generate changelogs and controller for connected schema
    data                 Generate changelog for the data in tables
    gencontrolfile       Generate a blank controller.xml as a sample
    update               Updates database to current version
    updatesql            Generates SQL to update database to current version
    rollback             Rolls back the state requested
    rollbacksql          Writes SQL to roll back the database to the state requested
    diff                 Writes description of differences between two databases to standard out.
    dbdoc                Generates Javadoc-like documentation based on current database and change log.
    changelogsync        Mark all changes as executed in the database.
    clearchecksums       Removes current checksums from  database.  On  next  update  changesets  that have already been
                         deployed will have their checksums recomputed, and  changesets that have not been deployed will
                         be deployed.
    listlocks            Lists who currently has locks on the database changelog.
    releaselocks         Releases all locks on the database changelog.
    status               Outputs list of unrun change sets.
    validate             Checks the changelog for errors.
    version              Display product version information
```

Comment: Thanks @ej-egyed ! It might work locally. However, when doing CI CD it may not be possible to install ```SQLcl``` on the build agent